# How to use QSignalMapper for multiple QLineEdits?

Tags: python, python-2.7, qt4, pyqt

I have around 20 QLineEdits on a particular application window.

I want the content of the QLineEdit to be cleared as soon as I click on it.

For a couple of QLIneEdits I use the below lambda function.

```
    self.StudentName.mousePressEvent = lambda event : self.StudentName.clear()
```

I am not sure how to implement QSignalMapper for this purpose as I have around 20 QLineEdits.
Can someone please briefly explain QSignalMapper.

Will I have to create an array of all the QLineEdit SIGNALs and then map it to the QSignalMapper SLOT.
Please suggest.

Comment: Why not just subclass `QLineEdit` and implement the behaviour you want? Also, I'm surprised that line of code works. I didn't think you could override PyQt methods by monkey-patching.

Comment: I am actually looking forward to not to write 20 SIGNALs. I want every QLineEdit to pass through the same clear() function everytime I click on it. Is it possible using QSignalMapper?

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can see, QSignalMapper is for the reverse problem, or collecting and collating signals from multiple inputs.

The simplest way to set multiple events to a simple behaviour is to do it in pure python:

```
 for edit in LineEdits:
     edit.mousePressEvent = lambda event : edit.clear()
```

where LineEdits is your list of widgets.